# Authentification with FB connect is called two times

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I try to use the SDK JavaScript of Facebook to allow user to login on my site with FB account.

Here my code :

```
<script>
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            facebookLogin();
        }
    });
}

function facebookLogin() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY_FB_APP_ID',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.10'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And then, in my html, I use the FB button to login or logout :

```
<fb:login-button data-auto-logout-link="true" scope="public_profile,email,user_birthday" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

When I click on this button, my function facebookLogin() is called 2 times (when I succeed login) and I don't understand why.
Someone have an idea ?

Comment: where do you call checkLoginState?

Comment: I made a mistake when I create the question : in fact, I call checkLoginState() when I click on the facebook button to connect. Then, when the connection succed (after Facebook popin), I get 2 times the console.log of my function facebookLogin().

Comment: In fact, called checkLoginState() or facebookLogin() in my onlogin of FB button made the same think : if connection succeed, I get 2 times the console.log()..
I didn't put all the code, but checkLoginState() is call only 1 time if I want to logout (with the same button).

Comment: can you share an example link?

Comment: I don't know how to do that...

Comment: well, put it on a server and post the link..

Comment: I try to put my code on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net but it doesn't work because the facebook button not appears and even if I change for a simple html button, I got an FB error because of theses websites are not allowed. I don't find another way to put my code online.. So thank you anyway to tried to help me.